# How can I convert a local date-time into UTC date-time?

Tags: date

I am trying to get a bash script working and in order to do so I need to transform a local time in `+%Y%m%d%H%M%S` format (example: "20150903170731")  into UTC time in the same format.

I know `date -u` can give me the current UTC time:

```sh
$ date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S  -u
20150903161322
```

Or, without the `-u` the local time (here, BST):

```sh
$ date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S
20150903171322
```

Now if I add an argument to `date`, I get an error:

```sh
echo "20150903154607" | xargs date +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S" -u
date: extra operand `20150903154607'
```

Is there any way I can do perform this conversion without such errors?

Comment: The version of unix is:                                                                                                                                                      x86_64 GNU/Linux
Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS

Answer (score 8):

To pass a date to use into `date`, use the `-d` option.  So your command would look something like `echo "20150903154607" | xargs date +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S" -u -d`.

It doesn't take exactly the date format you're supplying, though:

```sh
$ date -d 20150903154607
date: invalid date ‘20150903154607’
$ date -d 20150903\ 15:46:07
Thu Sep  3 15:46:07 BST 2015
```

So massage it a little first (GNU sed):

```sh
$ echo "20150903154607" \
   | sed -re 's/^([0-9]{8})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})$/\1\\ \2:\3:\4/' \
   | xargs date -u -d
Thu Sep  3 15:46:07 UTC 2015
```

To convert from local to UTC, you need to do a bit more, because `-u` affects the interpretation of both input and output dates:

```sh
$ echo "20150903171734" \
   | sed -re 's/^([0-9]{8})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})$/\1\\ \2:\3:\4/' \
   | xargs date +@%s -d \
   | xargs date -u +%Y%m%d%H%M%S -d
20150903161734
```

The first invocation of `date` above converts local time (according to `$TZ`) into seconds since the epoch; the second then converts epoch-seconds into UTC date and time.

Comment: just add the timezone explicitly to the input date. eg in the sed append 'BST'.

Comment: @meuh - perhaps; it depends on what HashGuy is actually trying to do (I didn't find it clear in the question).

Comment: I need the response back following same format of input 20150903171734 to 20150903161734 if that make sense... I need to use the string afterwards

Comment: I've edited with a local-to-UTC example.  I haven't tested to see what it does during the 1-hour window of ambiguous local time...

Comment: You see on the 27 March 2016 the time will go back to gmt again... I therefore think that Unix server should automatically updated to that time as well same the underlying database server... So logically between 27 March and June 2016 time will be gmt anyway

Comment: Is this a stupid assumption?

Comment: Toby look what i have done for testing this but still i am having problem storing the echo into a variable                            DateNew='20150903'
TimeNew='200001'
DateTimeNew_Suffix=${DateNew}${TimeNew}
newPrefix=`echo "${DateTimeNew_Suffix}"| sed -re 's/^([0-9]{8})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})$/\1\\ \2:\3:\4/'| xargs date +@%s -d | xargs date -u +%Y%m%d%H%M%S -d`
echo $newPrefix           this is the error date: extra operand `20:00:01'
Try `date --help' for more information.
date: option requires an argument -- 'd'
Try `date --help' for more information.

Comment: thanks toby .... i raised a different question this sed mask is working in output

Answer (score 4):

I also used something more simple:

```
date -u -d @$(date -d '2019-09-17 19:29:45' +%s)
Tue Sep 17 23:29:45 UTC 2019
```

you still need conversion from your custom format to the one understandable by `date`, it was described in the previous answer