# Issues with storing an echo of a date conversion into a string variable inunix

Tags: date, string, time, variable, echo

Apologies but this question comes from a question previously raised: [How can I convert a local date-time into UTC date-time?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/227312/how-can-i-convert-a-local-date-time-into-utc-date-time) Toby has been absolutely great helping me with some conversion string-->BST -->GMT but ow i am facing another i believe dummy issue.

my .sh is simple:

```
# variables needed for testing
DateNew="20150903"
TimeNew="200001"

# concatenating date and time 
DateTimeNew_Suffix=${DateNew}${TimeNew}

# storing the conversion provided by Toby Speight into a variable
newPrefix=`echo "${DateTimeNew_Suffix}"| sed -re 's/^([0-9]{8})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})$/\1\\ \2:\3:\4/'| xargs date +@%s -d | xargs date -u +%Y%m%d%H%M%S -d`

#printing that value
echo $newPrefix
```

expected would be: **"20150903190001"** which should be the value assigned as a String into $newPrefix however Unix itself is throwing this exception:

> date: extra operand `20:00:01' Try` date --help' for more information.
>
> date: option requires an argument -- 'd' Try `date --help' for more
>
> information.

Running the command on its own i get the output expected:

```
echo "20150903200001"    | sed -re 's/^([0-9]{8})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})$/\1\\ \2:\3:\4/'    | xargs date +@%s -d    | xargs date -u +%Y%m%d%H%M%S -d
```

**20150903190001**

how can I store this echo into the newPrefix variable as a string? it look like conversion date into the variable is failing but the echo is not.

any help?

Comment: Solution found :)   DateNew='20150903'
TimeNew='200001'
DateTimeNew_Suffix=${DateNew}${TimeNew}
newPrefix=$(sed -n 1p $filename | sed -re 's/^([0-9]{8})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})$/\1\\ \2:\3:\4/'| xargs date +@%s -d| xargs date -u +%Y%m%d%H%M%S -d)
echo $newPrefix
echo "$newPrefix"

Comment: i had to use $() to store the actual sed instead echo - as i was triyng to pull it from a file itself.... but please if someone has a more elegant solution please do let me know...so happyyyyyy!!!!! i figured out

Comment: if you answer your own question, you should write up an answer and accept it

Comment: I 'll do it hwillie

Answer (score -1):

Solution found :)

```
DateNew='20150903'
TimeNew='200001'
DateTimeNew_Suffix=${DateNew}${TimeNew}
newPrefix=$(sed -n 1p $filename | sed -re 's/^([0-9]{8})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})$/\1\\ \2:\3:\4/'| xargs date +@%s -d| xargs date -u +%Y%m%d%H%M%S -d)
echo $newPrefix
echo "$newPrefix"
```

Comment: You've introduced an unexplained new `$filename` variable. What is this?